# Is there any way to suppress Flash's FileReference.upload method from passing "Upload" : "Submit Query" form parameter?

Tags: flash, upload

Flash 9 / AS3 question here.

For some reason Flash adds a parameter called "Upload" with the value "Submit Query" when you call FileReference.upload.  This is causing a problem with an application we are writing. We need Flash not to send form parameters that we don't explicitly tell it to.

Can we suppress this somehow?